# ElasticSearch Query parameter for approximate filter

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have in ElasticSearch an object indexed with the name "Ronaldinho", I'm trying to create an approximate filter search, for example, when I try to search for "Ronaldo" the object "Ronaldinho" can be shown.

```
http://127.0.0.1//elasticsearch/channels/channel/_search?q=*Ronaldo*
```

I tried this way, but as it has different words the result does not appear.

Comment: Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const userInput = "Ronaldo";

const searchQuery = userInput.split('').reduce((agg, ele) => {return `${agg}${ele}*`}, "");

console.log(searchQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not help me, because how do I apply if the filter comes from a field that the user typed .. if the user typed "Ronaldo" what logic for me to apply a regex in "Ronald*o"

Comment: I see your point. I edit the answer check if this will help you. This will match any combination. You can take the user input and alter it with this function before sending it to elasticsearch

Comment: In fact, this is still not what I need, because if the user types "Renaldo" by mistake ... I would like to make a filter by approximation and show results that may make sense to my user understand? Ex:
"Renaldo" and "Ronaldo" only one word diff..